# A patch is preventing the system from starting - after KB981852

Tags: windows-7

Anyone else experienced after update? Seems certain hardware configurations are only affected. I can't boot to anything but console. I've tried to remove all "removable" hardware. All I need is to boot the damn system just once, to run certain software in order to make backups, then I can reinstall it or even better, use os x.

Comment: Another post about the same issue, damn one is enough I think.

Comment: I'm trying to produce the problem from various aspects, thus breaking down it into parts!

Comment: Use MSIZAP to remove the patch, and see if that is the actual problem. Runs from console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go through below url... one user had resolved his issues some what similar to you

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vistawu/thread/df590178-0a95-43e2-b5d3-3ba67dcc78bf